# How do scrapyd deploy project to remote?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

`scrapyd` can help deploy project.
It seems like it create egg and upload it??
But where did it upload to ??

I mean:
when I use `scrapyd-deploy <target> -p <project>`  deploy to `http://1.2.3.4:6800`
Can I find it on `http://1.2.3.4:6800`

And the scrapyd tasks log on 6800 port ,do they have expiration date to clear it ??
Can I find the log on `http://1.2.3.4:6800`

How did it run?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy with scrapdy, what response do you get?

However, after deploying successfull, you can not call http://1.2.3.4:6800 and have a list of your Spiders. Fortunately, Mahmoud M. Abdel-Fattah programmed a super simple and basic scrapyd web Interface. You can find it here http://mahmoud.abdel-fattah.net/2012/07/04/super-simple-and-basic-scrapyd-web-interface/

Copy and paste lines 1 - 85 into a .html-file and edit line 9 from
    `var scrapyd_url = 'http://localhost:6800/';`
to
    `var scrapyd_url = 'http://1.2.3.4:6800';`
or whatever your deploy path is and edit line 11 from
    `var project_name = 'bkam';`
to
    `var project_name = '<your scrapy project name>';`